# Magento : How to use or upload animated .GIF for products and page images?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I need to upload animated gif for the current site I am working on.
But magento keeps converting it to something else.
What settings are to be changed to upload animated images?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151682/magento-show-animated-gif-image-for-product try changing this file and upload gif image for product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It converts it into another gif image.

i.e. if you upload `photo.gif` it will now be `photo_1.gif`

Use an FTP Program to upload the original `photo.gif`, but rename it to `photo_1.gif` and overwrite the smaller converted file.

The animated gif should work now.

This works on Magento 1.9x for Category images

Comment: This worked nicely.  The only problem I have now is how to make the client understand how to do this.

Comment: what about products image? want to upload .gif image for products.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file from 
path: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php

Replace the function,

```
 public function getUrl()
    {
        $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
        $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $this->_newFile);
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
    }
```

with

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
        $file = ('gif' == strtolower(pathinfo($this->_baseFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) ? $this->_baseFile : $this->_newFile;
        $path = str_replace($baseDir . DS, "", $file);
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . str_replace(DS, '/', $path);
    }
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: after doing this till not working so what do next. Have you any idea?

Comment: Did you uploaded the .gif image to the product? Can you see the image in backend or it is not uploaded in backend also?

Comment: it's uploaded in admin and also display there but not working as like .GIF image in admin also it is look like a .JPG/.JPEG image.